# "I got to watch this movie" or "I got an opportunity to watch this movie"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Ok, recently, I made an update on a website like this :

> So, finally I got to watch this movie ...

Basically, what I was trying to say is that "I got an opportunity to watch this movie". I was little skeptical about the usage of *got* here.

Is this statement correct:

> I got to watch this movie

instead of

> I got an opportunity to watch this movie

Comment: And you downvoted for that. Wow, so thoughtful of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference. *I got to watch the movie* means that I watched the movie. If, on the other hand, I say *I got the opportunity to watch the movie*, then the reader knows I was in a position to watch the movie but does not know for sure that I did in fact watch it.

Comment: Wow, that made it perfectly clear.You just pointed out the minute difference very hard to find.thanks!!